# How to fix this error while running a discord bot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots

```
Debugger attached.
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'node:events'
```

I am using discord.js and node.js on Visual Studio Code

Comment: Hi Adam, you're going to have to provide more information for us to help you. Please look at [this post that describes how to ask a good SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue, you need to update your nodejs to **v16.6** or higher version from here,

[Download](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)